# Speed enforced by radar - why the extra verbiage

Tags: traffic, new-york-city, law-enforcement

Jurisdiction NYC.
Sample speed limit sign.

```
+-------------+
|             |
| Speed Limit |
|      NN     |
|             |
| Enforced by |
|    radar    |
+-------------+
```

- Why must the authority specify "enforced by radar"?
- What if they did not include this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Speed limits can be enforced by any means (except photo-radar) in most U.S. jurisdictions without notice that it is being used. Those laws are close to being uniform in the U.S. due to federal coordination on federally funded roads, even though state and local laws are what governs them directly.

Some U.S. jurisdictions prohibit the issuance of photo-radar speeding tickets without notice before entering the photo-radar picture taking zone. I'd have to research further to see if New York City does.

The purpose of the language on the sign is to make drivers more fearful of being caught in circumstances where they don't see someone trying to enforce the law, not to have greater legal effect.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this last small paragraph is the real point: further inhibit going faster than the speed limit. As with many mundane things, the point isn't really to arrest people or issue tickets (apart from the traditional "speed traps" and such), but to inhibit the behavior in the first place. :)  Such issues _may_ indeed be amenable to the idea that a threat of nearly-sure punishment _deters_ the undesirable behavior... in contrast to many other situations and issues.

Comment: The wording was improved some 60+ years ago: signs used to say "controlled by radar", which suggests that they have a magical means of keeping you from speeding.

Comment: I always presumed that this message originated in the early days of radar enforcement because using radar without disclosing it had been ruled by some court to be unjust (or was at least seen as unjust by the legislature). @user6726 in many languages "control" means "check," but this is the first time I've heard of its use in that sense in English except as a mistranslation from one of those languages.

Comment: @user6726, or they could just go [the XKCD route](https://what-if.xkcd.com/87/).

Comment: I always thought it was to let motorists know that they were enforcing the speed limit by assessing if you were over it by radar, as opposed to seeing you blow past the general speed of traffic on a given road.  The idea is that if motorists know that there is precision into the judgement of speeding vs. not speeding and not an officer that's acting on what he visually sees.  Of course, then there's the drivers in my state who believe that the speed limit is how fast you must be going in order to see that the drivers passing are flipping you off.  Any lower will just be flesh colored blurs.

Comment: Incidentally, signs saying the speed is monitored by aircraft is almost certainly lying. Some districts will make a ceremonial flight every few years, but speed monitoring by aircraft is prohibitively expensive.